# Room Query: find within list is always returning null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have an entity where one of the fields is a MutableList. I want to return all the user ids that contain the given ID in that list. The query always return an empty list. If I open the database though I can see that the fields are stored properly and that there are user IDs to be returned. What am I doing wrong?

Data class:

```
@Entity
data class User(
  @PrimaryKey
  @SerializedName("id")
  @ColumnInfo(name = "userId")
  var userId: String,
  @SerializedName("username")
  var userName: String = "",
  var city: String = "",
  var postsIds: MutableList<String>
)
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
   @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE postsIds LIKE :id")
   fun getForPost(id: String): List<User>

// some other queries
}
```

Repository:

```
fun getUsersForPost(id: String): LiveData<List<User>> {
        val data = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val query = async(Dispatchers.IO) { userDao.getForPost(id) }
            val result = query.await()
            if (result.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                // todo fetch from the API
            } else {
                data.postValue(result)
            }
        }
        return data
    }
```

Usage:

```
ViewModel: 

fun getPost(id: String): Post {
  val post = repository.getPost(id)
  _postEditors.value = repository.getUsersForPost(id).value
  return post
}

Fragment: 

viewModel.postEditors.observe(this, Observer { 
  Log.d(TAG, $it)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you seem to be using the **`LIKE`***(wildcard search)* instead of **`=`***(exact match)* operator:

```java
    @Dao
    interface UserDao {

        @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE postsIds = :id")
        fun getForPost(id: String): List<User>

        // some other queries
    }
```

Now I'm sure you have your own use cases for doing that. When using **Room 1.1.1+** you need to add a wildcard **%** to your **`LIKE`** operator as follows otherwise it might not work:

```java
    @Dao
    interface UserDao {

        @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE postsIds LIKE `%` || :id || `%`")
        fun getForPost(id: String): List<User>

        // some other queries
    }
```

> **N.B:** `|| is concatenation operator` and `% wildcard` read up on
>   [SQLite wildcards](https://www.javatpoint.com/sqlite-like-clause)
>
> This would result in a search for anything that matches the provided `id`
>    **a.k.a**: [Full Text Search](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbusage/full-text-search-what-is-it.html), if you only want to match anything starting with `id` then you'd do the following:
>
> ```java
>    @Dao
>    interface UserDao {
>
>        @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE postsIds LIKE :id || `%`")
>        fun getForPost(id: String): List<User>
>
>        // some other queries
> }
> ```

Just another hint, if you really want to use **Full Text Search** with Room then i'd suggest you update to **v2.1** which added [FTS4](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Fts4) support, and here's a nice detailed read on [Medium](https://medium.com/@sienatime/enabling-sqlite-fts-in-room-2-1-75e17d0f0ff8)

Answer (score 0):

Just by reviewing your code, I think you're doing `userDao.getForPost(id)` but likely you should be doing `userDao.getForPost("%"+id+"%")`